# Changing a String (filename extension)

Tags: assembly, masm, x86-16

I'm new here. Here is the deal:
I need to read a filename and then verify if it ends with ".IN", if not, I need to add it in order to open the file. After that, I need to create a file, with the same filename, but ending with ".OUT", replacing the ".IN"

```
GetFileName proc    near
    lea     bx,MsgEnterFilename
    call    printf_s ;It prints the string above
    mov     ah,0ah
    lea     dx,FileNameBuffer
    mov     byte ptr FileNameBuffer,100
    int     21h
    lea     si,FileNameBuffer+2
    lea     di,FileName
    mov     cl,FileNameBuffer+1
    mov     ch,0
    mov     ax,ds
    mov     es,ax
    rep     movsb
    mov     byte ptr es:[di],0 ;Puts a '\0' at the end
    ret
GetFileName endp

fileNameInfo proc near ;Puts ".IN" and ".OUT"
    lea     si, FileName
    lea     di, FileNameCopy
    mov     cx, MAXSTRING ; MAXSTRING is set to 256, yeah, I am copying beyond the string end
    rep movsb 

    ; Search for ".IN"
    mov     si, 0

start_filename_length:                
    mov     al, FileNameCopy[si]  

    cmp     al, 0
    je      end_filename_length

    inc     FileNameLength
    inc     FileNameLengthAux

    add     si, 1
    jmp     start_filename_length
end_filename_length:

    sub     FileNameLengthAux, 2 ; To begin the test in the last 3 bytes (".IN")
    mov     si, word ptr FileNameLengthAux
    cmp     FileNameCopy[si], "."
    je      test_i
    jmp     no_extension
test_i:
    inc     si
    mov     si, word ptr FileNameLengthAux
    cmp     FileNameCopy[si], "I"
    je      test_n
    cmp     FileNameCopy[si], "i"
    je      test_n
    jmp     no_extension
test_n:
    inc     si  ; last byte
    mov     si, word ptr FileNameLengthAux
    cmp     FileNameCopy[si], "N" 
    je      correct_extension
    cmp     FileNameCopy[si], "n"
    je      correct_extension
    ;jmp    no_extension

no_extensao: ;wrong extension counts as no extension
    inc     FileNameLengthAux       ;goes to '\0' position
    mov     si, word ptr FileNameLengthAux
    mov     FileNameCopy[si], "."
    inc     si
    mov     FileNameCopy[si], "O"
    inc     si
    mov     FileNameCopy[si], "U"
    inc     si
    mov     FileNameCopy[si], "T"
    inc     si
    mov     FileNameCopy[si], 0 ;End the string

    lea     si, FileNameCopy
    lea     di, FileNameOut
    mov     cx, MAXSTRING ; copy 256 bytes
rep movsb

    jmp     return_filename_info

correct_extension: ;copyies till the "."
    mov     bl, FileNameLengthAux
    mov     FileNameLength, bl
    sub     FileNameLength, 2
    lea     si, FileNameCopy
    lea     di, FileNameOut
    mov     ch, 0
    mov     cl, FileNameLengthAux
rep movsb
    mov     si, word ptr FileNameLengthAux ; it is on "." position
    inc     si
    mov     FileNameOut[si], "O"
    inc     si
    mov     FileNameOut[si], "U"
    inc     si
    mov     FileNameOut[si], "T"
    inc     si
    mov     FileNameOut[si], 0 ;End the string
    ;jmp    return_filename_info

return_filename_info:

    ret
fileNameInfo endp
```

Thanks for the help =D

Comment: You haven't stated what the issue is exactly...

Comment: I get "Invalid operands" on mov  String[si], FileBuffer

Comment: (hit enter in the comment before finishing it)
Is the code right?

Comment: There is no such instruction in this code.  I don't see `FileBuffer` anywhere?

Comment: sorry, in fact that problem is not related. I just want to know if this code should work, replacing the .IN with .OUT

Comment: already solved my problem, now the FileNameIn and the FileNameOut are right. I tested them out printing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> sub     FileNameLengthAux, 2 ; To begin the test in the last 3 bytes (".IN")
> ```

This is the famous *off by one error*! You need to subtract **3**.
Verify this with an example. If the filename were "A.IN", the length will be 4 and you will want to start looking for the "." character at offset `SI=1`. Do the math: 4 - **3** = 1.

> ```
> test_i:
>     inc     si
>     mov     si, word ptr FileNameLengthAux
> ```

Why do you destroy the (correctly) incremented value for `SI` ?

> ```
> test_i:
>     inc     si
>     mov     si, word ptr FileNameLengthAux
> ```

Same problem here.

> ```
> mov     bl, FileNameLengthAux
> mov     FileNameLength, bl
> sub     FileNameLength, 2
> ```

How do you expect this to give a correct final *FileNameLength* ?
*FileNameLengthAux* already was smaller than the original length (you subtracted 2), and here you make it even smaller (subtracting another 2)!
All it takes is returning a length that's exactly **1** bigger than what you started with.

---

In case your program didn't find an extension (".IN"), you don't update the *FileNameLength* at all. Just add **4**, since that's the length of the appended ".OUT".

Comment: hey, thanks for your considerations, I didn't thought at some of these points before, or ever was paying attention =P I have done some modification since, and I would like you to help me with that

https://pastebin.com/LM0Ep5wn

Comment: between the lines 113-123 I should print the names generated, but I only get blank on Copy and Out, and the In is the same I entered in the program when running

Comment: In addition to the good advice in this answer, at line 517, you need to subtract 2 from *FileNameLengthAux*!

Answer (score 0):

The calls are in the main program PS.: Sorry, the comments are in portuguese

```
;Constants
AscUpi              equ     "I"
AscLowi             equ     "i"
AscUpn              equ     "N"
AscLown             equ     "n"
AscUpo              equ     "O"
AscLowo             equ     "o"
AscUpu              equ     "U"
AscLowu             equ     "u"
AscUpt              equ     "T"
AscLowt             equ     "t"
AscDot              equ     "."

call    GetFileName
call    GetFileNameLength
call    VerifyFileName
call    GenFileNameOut

VerifyFileName proc near
    mov     dx, FileNameLength
    mov     FileNameLengthAux, dx ; SI considera FileName[0] como sendo a 1a posição, como vetores em C
    sub     FileNameLengthAux, 3 ;FileNameLength - 3 -> posição do . em ".IN"
    mov     si, FileNameLengthAux ;"."
    ;mov    dx, "."
    cmp     FileNameIn[si], AscDot
    je      testa_i
    jmp     no_extension
testa_i:
    inc     si  ;FileNameLength - 2 -> posição do I em ".IN" ;"i" ou "I"
    ;mov    dx, "I"
    cmp     FileNameIn[si], AscUpi
    je      testa_n
    ;mov    dx, "i"
    cmp     FileNameIn[si], AscLowi
    je      testa_n
    jmp     no_extension
testa_n:
    inc     si ;FileNameLength - 1 -> posição do N em ".IN" ;"n" ou "N"
    ;mov    dx, "N"
    cmp     FileNameIn[si], AscUpn
    je      right_extension
    ;mov    dx, "n"
    cmp     FileNameIn[si], AscLown
    je      right_extension
    jmp     no_extension
no_extension: ;Inclui extensao errada, caso seja entrado 123.abc, será transformado em 123.abc.in (.in são os últimos 3 caracteres)
    mov     dx, FileNameLength
    mov     FileNameLengthAux, dx
    sub     FileNameLengthAux, 1
    mov     si, FileNameLengthAux
    inc     si
    ;mov    dx, "."
    mov     byte ptr FileNameIn[si], AscDot
    inc     FileNameLength ; Ajusta o FileNameLength somando os 3 caracteres que acabaram de ser adicionados
    inc     si
    ;mov    dx, "I"
    mov     byte ptr FileNameIn[si], AscUpi ; No PDF está especificado '.IN'
    inc     FileNameLength ; Ajusta o FileNameLength somando os 3 caracteres que acabaram de ser adicionados
    inc     si
    ;mov    dx, "N"
    mov     byte ptr FileNameIn[si], AscUpn
    inc     FileNameLength ; Ajusta o FileNameLength somando os 3 caracteres que acabaram de ser adicionados
    inc     si
    mov     FileNameIn[si], 0 ; Fecha a String do nome de arquivo
    ;jmp    right_extension
right_extension:
    ;FILENAMEIN ESTA CORRETO
    ret
VerifyFileName endp
GenFileNameOut proc near
    ;O nome do arquivo de entrada está correto agora, e o tamanho foi atualizado caso tenha sido necessário
    ;Copiar o FileNameIn para FileNameOut e fazer os ajustes (.IN -> .OUT)

    mov     cx, FileNameLength
    lea     si, FileNameIn
    lea     di, FileNameOut
    rep     movsb ; Cópia de strings

    ;agora FileNameOut = FileNameIn

    mov     ax, FileNameLength
    mov     FileNameLengthAux, ax
    sub     FileNameLengthAux, 2 ; Vai para a posição do "I" em ".IN"
    mov     si, FileNameLengthAux
    mov     byte ptr FileNameOut[si], "O" ; Subtitui o 'I' por 'O'
    inc     si
    mov     byte ptr FileNameOut[si], "U" ; Subtitui o 'N' por 'U'
    inc     si
    mov     byte ptr FileNameOut[si], "T" ; Subtitui o 0 por 'T'
    inc     si
    mov     byte ptr FileNameOut[si], 0   ; Subtitui o 0 por 0

    ;FILENAMEOUT ESTA CORRETO
    ;call   NewLine
    ;lea    bx, FileNameOut
    ;call   printf_s

    ;FileNameOut está pronto
    ;jmp    return_filename_out
return_filename_out:
    ret
GenFileNameOut endp
GetFileNameLength proc near
    mov     si, 0 ;primeira posicao da string
inicio_filename_length: 
    mov     al, FileNameIn[si]
    cmp     al, 0
    je      fim_filename_length
    inc     FileNameLength      
    inc     FileNameLengthAux   ;Cópia de FileNameLength
    inc     si
    ;add    si, 1
    jmp     inicio_filename_length
fim_filename_length:
    ret
GetFileNameLength endp
```

Comment: sorry, I thought I should put as answer the solution